# How to setup Spring security to auto-login with html parameters

Tags: grails, spring-security

Let's say I want to send out URLs through emails that automatically log you in to a particular web page. Something like:

http://example.com/showSomeStuff?username=fredsmith&token=dsamlKLDhFDhmlkjdeuaq3a

In other words, have the token that provides the security within the URL itself.

Having searched the Spring documentation and stackoverflow, nobody seems to have addressed this. All the existing spring security strategies seem to assume that if you are not yet logged in, we have to first redirect you to a login web page, where the user will do something and THEN it can take you to where you are going. None of them have in mind that you will be authenticated directly.

I've figured out how to do it and will provide an answer below, for anyone else who might want to do it. It's Grails Groovy code, though I'm sure anyone using Java will easily adapt it. If anyone knows a better way of doing it, feel free to provide your own answer. Obviously doing something like this has security implications, so whether it's a good idea for your use case to do it, is something you need to consider.

Answer (score -1):

First we need a filter which will catch the scenario we are interested in. Standard authentication filters in Spring usually inherit from AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter. But this class doesn't seem to really envisige a scenario like this, so I had to override doFilter, and hack a few of the details. However, I only modified the minimum needed to make this work. If you compare the small details changed between AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter and my TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter, you will see what needed to change:

```
package holder

import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.ServletException
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@GrailsCompileStatic
class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter  {
    private SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionStrategy = new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    TokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        // default is this login strategy is available for all pages on the site
        this("/**")
    }

    TokenAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl)
    }

    @Override
    Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String username = request.getParameter("username")
        String token = request.getParameter("token")
        if (username && token) {
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, token));
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

    @Override
    void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        // You could delete this if you want it to apply to all URLs
        if (!requiresAuthentication(request, response)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            return;
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Request is to process authentication");
        }

        Authentication authResult;
        try {
            authResult = attemptAuthentication(request, response);
            if (authResult == null) {
                // Unlike the super class, we consider a null response an opportunity for the user
                // to use the usual spring login screen, so we call change.doFilter before returning
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }
            sessionStrategy.onAuthentication(authResult, request, response);
        }
        catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException failed) {
            logger.error(
                    "An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.",
                    failed);
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
            return;
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException failed) {
            // Authentication failed, wrong credentials
            // Here the user gets 401, but you could instead redirect
            // to the login screen if you called chain.doFilter
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
            return;
        }

        // We need to successfully authenticate before calling the chain
        successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        // Here by calling the chain, we ensure that we continue onto the destination URL
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Now we need an AuthenticationProvider which can handle this scenario. We could have created our own AbstractAuthenticationToken subclass, but reusing UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken works for us here. I used the GormUserDetailsService as a fast track to loading the user's roles/authorities, but that's fairly trivial and easy to handle yourself. @Transactional ensures the class has access to using database functions to lookup the User.

```
package holder

import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GormUserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

@GrailsCompileStatic
class TokenAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    GormUserDetailsService userDetailsService

    @Transactional
    @Override
    Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication

        User user
        User.withTransaction {
            user = User.findByUsername((String)token.principal)
        }

        if (user && user.authorizeToken((String)token.credentials)) {
            UserDetails det = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.username)
            token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.principal, token.credentials, det.getAuthorities())
            return token
        }else{
            return null
        }
    }

    @Override
    boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class)
    }

}
```

The standard success handler tries to redirect you to where you were before you entered the login screen. Since we haven't been sidetracked to a login screen, we can just make a no-op empty success handler. We could have hacked the Filter to bypass any calls to success handlers, but I left the concept in the code, in case you have any reason to override it..

```
package holder

import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

@GrailsCompileStatic
class TokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // NO-OP
    }
}
```

Now we need to setup the beans in Grails' resources.groovy. Make sure you don't name the bean for the TokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler as "authenticationSuccessHandler", name it something else like noopAuthenticationSuccessHandler, otherwise you'll break the usual login screens.

```
beans = {
    noopAuthenticationSuccessHandler holder.TokenAuthenticationSuccessHandler
    tokenAuthenticationProvider (holder.TokenAuthenticationProvider) {
        userDetailsService = ref('userDetailsService')
    }
    tokenAuthenticationFilter (holder.TokenAuthenticationFilter) {
        authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
        rememberMeServices = ref('rememberMeServices')
        authenticationSuccessHandler = ref('noopAuthenticationSuccessHandler')
    }
}
```

And we need to set a high priority level to our filter in Bootstrap.groovy, to make sure our filter gets to it before the standard ones.

```
package holder

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityFilterPosition
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('tokenAuthenticationFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER.order + 10)
    }
}
```

And there you have it. Now any URLs that have a username= and token= parameters will be redirected into your security scheme, and provided user.authorizeToken says its ok, they'll be able to access the page, and be logged in with that user's credentials.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by OWASP [Information exposure through query strings in url](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url)

> Information exposure through query strings in URL is when sensitive
> data is passed to parameters in the URL. This allows attackers to
> obtain sensitive data such as usernames, passwords, tokens (authX),
> database details, and any other potentially sensitive data. **Simply
> using HTTPS does not resolve this vulnerability**.

Sensitive information may be exposed in the following:

- Referer Header
- Web Logs
- Shared Systems
- Browser History
- Browser Cache
- Shoulder Surfing

Sending a token as a url parameter is a **BIG** no no, and a **massive security** risk as we cant guarentee that https is always used.

This means that **anyone can read the token**, if its not sent using TLS and will be logged all around the world through every proxy etc that this request goes through.

Also remember that urls are usually stored in browser history if a malicious actor gets access to the machine.

### **Tokens should only be sent as headers or in the body**

During a man in the middle attack someone malicious could just take the url and authenticate as the user IF TLS is not used.

If you want to login a user from an email, etc they should click on the link that accesses an unauthenticated endpoint and the endpoint should have them login.

### **NEVER send sensitive information in the uri.**